# Django - common data in every templates

Tags: python, django

I need to pass achieve section to every pages of my blog. From Google, I end up with creating a context_processor like this

```
# processor.py 

from myblog.models import Post

def get_date(request):
  return {'dates' : Post.objects.order_by('created')}
```

this is base.html

```
<ul>
    {% for d in dates %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ d.created|date:"M-Y"}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and this is the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
  "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
  "django.core.context_processors.debug",
  "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
  "django.core.context_processors.media",
  "django.core.context_processors.static",
  "django.core.context_processors.tz",
  "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
  'myblog.processor.get_date',
)
```

Finally, in order to let the date appear on page, i need to pass the RequestContext in every views. This makes me have to repeat the code in every views, but I could use solutions from [here](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2008/may/10/getting-requestcontext-your-templates/) to overcome it. However, base on [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131073/why-should-i-not-always-pass-a-django-request-context-in-a-view), it could lead to performance issue.

In the end, what is the optimal solution for this small task in Django ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of modern [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/) do all job with `RequestContext` for you so you don't need to worry. If you like old-style function based views - there's a [`render`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts/__init__.py#L22) function.

That "performance issue" is about specific  `django.core.context_processors.request`. As long as you don't use it - everything is fine.